# errors generated by express validator with node express

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I am using nodejs, express, & express-validator. I am trying to use express validator on my sign_up page . Express-validator generates the errors in an array of objects. 
the error: 

**Result {

formatter: [Function: formatter],

errors: [

{

value: undefined,

msg: 'Please Enter a Valid Username',

param: 'username',

location: 'body'

},

{

value: undefined, 

msg: 'Please enter a valid email', 

param: 'email', 

location: 'body'

},

{

value: undefined,

msg: 'Please enter a valid password',

param: 'password',

location: 'body'

}

]

}**

I use postman to test the register operation
and send the following in the request:

**{
"username":"ruba",
"email":"test@gmail.com",
"password":"1234544545@"**

}

my user.js code:

```
// Filename : user.js

const express = require("express");
const { check, validationResult} = require("express-validator");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const router = express.Router();

const User = require("../model/User");

/**
 * @method - POST
 * @param - /signup
 * @description - User SignUp
 */

router.post(
    "/signup",
    [
        check("username", "Please Enter a Valid Username")
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
        check("email", "Please enter a valid email").isEmail(),
        check("password", "Please enter a valid password").isLength({
            min: 6
        })
    ],
    async (req, res) => {
   
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        console.log(errors);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            console.log("error sign");

            return res.status(400).json({
                errors: errors.array()
            });
            console.log("error sign2");

        }
        console.log("error sign3");

        const {
            username,
            email,
            password
        } = req.body;
        try {
            let user = await User.findOne({
                email
            });
            if (user) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    msg: "User Already Exists"
                });
            }

            user = new User({
                username,
                email,
                password
            });

            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

            await user.save();

            const payload = {
                user: {
                    id: user.id
                }
            };

            jwt.sign(
                payload,
                "randomString", {
                    expiresIn: 10000
                },
                (err, token) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    res.status(200).json({
                        token
                    });
                }
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            res.status(500).send("Error in Saving");
        }
    }
);


module.exports = router;
```

my index code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const user = require("./routes/user"); //new addition
const InitiateMongoServer = require("./config/db");

// Initiate Mongo Server
InitiateMongoServer();

const app = express();

// PORT
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

// Middleware
//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "API Working" });
});


app.use("/user", user);

app.listen(PORT, (req, res) => {
  console.log(`Server Started at PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

so please help me. what is the problem??

**Edit: It's solved. the problem was in the postman settings (the contents type must be JSON)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enabled

```js
app.use(express.json());
```

Because I cant see any kind of problem with you code (about the express-validator).

I suggest you after this fix, you to change check to body since you wants only to check the content of body.

I'm using an middleware to helps to me keep my code short and legible, and I'll share with you

```js
function validation(validations: Array<ValidationChain>) {
    return async (req: Request, _res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        await Promise.all(validations.map((v) => v.run(req)));
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (errors.isEmpty()) {
            return next();
        }
        const msg = errors
            .array()
            .map((er) => `${er.param}`)
            .join(', ');
        const issue = new Issue(400, `missing or invalid params: ${msg}`);
        next(issue);
    };
}
```

The usage:

```js
router.post(
    '/login',
    validation([body('email').isEmail(), body('password').isLength({ min: 5, max: 30 })]),
    async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
        ...
    });
``'
```

Comment: yes, I enabled it but it's not working.
thank you for giving me another code.
I'll try it

Comment: When you comment your validation code, and print req.body you can see your data there? If not, maybe you are "injecting" app.use(express.json()) after your route registration.

Comment: I try it but the printed result is (undefined)

I think app.use(express.json()) is in the right place

Comment: Could you share the file where you define your express app?

Comment: I edit my question and add the index.js code.
please return to the question. I'm new in stackoverflow and I don't know how to share files

Comment: No problem, I'm new here too. Well your code seems right, how are you requesting this route in postman? Are you setting content-type to application/json right?

Comment: I did not know ! It is the first time I use postman. I set the content type now.
The  code worked.
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You're welcome! I think will be good if you edit your question, describing that the problem was with your request in postman. Glad to help you!